# Complementar codigo con una clase

Tags: java

Hola buenas tengo esta clase llamada CostPersonal y tengo que crear una clase treballador que la complemente pero no entiendo cuando hace referencia a treballador.DIRECTOR

```
public class CostPersonal {

    static float CalculaCostDelPersonal(Treballador treballadors[]) {
        float costFinal = 0;
        Treballador treballador;

        for (int i = 0; i < treballadors.length; i++) {
            treballador = treballadors[i];

            if (treballador.getTipusTreballador() == Treballador.DIRECTOR ||
            treballador.getTipusTreballador() == Treballador.SUBDIRECTOR) {
                costFinal = costFinal + treballador.getNomina();
            } else {
                costFinal = costFinal + treballador.getNomina() +
                    (treballador.getHoresExtres() * 20);
            }
        }
        return costFinal;
    }
```

Comment: Como deseas complementar el código a que te refieres?

Comment: Hola, pues no entiendo como tiene que ser el metodo getTipusTreballador para poder hacer la compracion con Treballador.DIRECTOR o treballador.SUBDIRECTOR.

Comment: Agrega el codigo de la clase Treballador, al parecer solo necesitas una explicación de lo que realiza cierto?

Comment: `getTipusTreballador()` te devolvería el tipo de trabajador, que podría ser una ¿constante? tal que `DIRECTOR`, o `SUBDIRECTOR` u otro. Lo que no se entiende es por qué lo evalúas contra una propiedad de la misma clase ¿?  en vez de hacer: `if (treballador.getTipusTreballador().equals("DIRECTOR")) ...`

Comment: Sii alf inal en la clase Treballador añadi dos constantes y todo genial!!!Graciass!